# What is a good third party transaction API platform to use for ROR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, transactions, paypal, payment-gateway, braintree

I have been looking at paypal for a online transaction, but I wanted to know if there are other 3rd party vendor that offer a good service at a good price ( transaction fee) and ease of use of API for ruby on rails application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Braintree](http://www.braintreepaymentsolutions.com/). There's a [Braintree Ruby gem](http://www.braintreepaymentsolutions.com/gateway/ruby) that makes integration easy, and [pricing](http://www.braintreepaymentsolutions.com/pricing) is very competitive. And you don't have to fear "[the paypal call](http://ebaystrategies.blogs.com/ebay_strategies/2010/02/beware-of-the-paypal-call-and-what-to-do-today-to-mitigate-large-paypal-reserves.html)".

Answer (score 0):

[Authorize.net](http://www.authorize.net/) has a better pricing plan that PayFloPro by Paypal, with very similar functionality.